# Trouble with wp_nav_menu, conditional tags and fallback_cb

Tags: navigation

I created some menus, and now I'm trying to set up a conditional construction with wp_nav_menu in header.php, but the behavior is not really as expected. I'm doing something like

```
<?php 
if ( is_front_page() )  
{
     wp_nav_menu( array( 'container_class' => 'menu-header', 'menu' => '68' ));
} 
elseif ( is_single() )  
{
     wp_nav_menu( array( 'container_class' => 'menu-header', 'menu' => '69' ) );
} 
else 
{
     wp_nav_menu( array( 'container_class' => 'menu-header', 'menu' => '33' ));
} 
?>
```

the last "else" catches 404s and pages, but with archives (categories, tags, search, author, ...) the menu falls back to the default fallback (wp_list_pages) instead of menu 33. Any ideas why this is happening? Note: I'm modifying the TwentyTen theme.

Comment: Does menu 33 exist? (that ID is definately correct?) If so, does it have any items? ... also, any plugins installed? And if so, have you tried without them enabled?

Answer (score 2):

Ideally, you should be passing the "theme_location" argument to wp_nav_menu().

Register your three menus in functions.php:

```
register_nav_menus( array(
     'front_page' => 'Front Page Menu',
     'single' => 'Single Post Menu',
     'default' => 'Default Menu'
) );
```

Then, replace your code above with:

```
if ( is_front_page() )  
{
     wp_nav_menu( array( 'container_class' => 'menu-header', 'theme_location' => 'front_page' ));
} 
elseif ( is_single() )  
{
     wp_nav_menu( array( 'container_class' => 'menu-header', 'theme_location' => 'single' ) );
} 
else 
{
     wp_nav_menu( array( 'container_class' => 'menu-header', 'theme_location' => 'default' ));
}
```

Then, ensure the appropriate custom menu is defined for each Theme Location, via Dashboard -> Appearance -> Menus

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the `menu` parameter, you can also use the `name` or the `slug`. Please try those too. If you're sure about the ID, then you could also try using `menu_id` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the problem was somehow caused by a [pre_get_posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) filter in my functions.php. In fact, I had an issue with this filter [before](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/troubleshooting-wordpress-31-master-list#post-2007723), so I should've known ;) Cheers!